# Is maximum/minimum voltage always compared as difference voltage for a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, diodes, avr

Let's take the [ATmega328P](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) for example.
It has a minimum input voltage of `-0.5` and maximum input voltage of `Vcc + 0.5`.

[image]

But what if I say `Vcc = -5 V` and `GND = 0 V`?
Will it break then, because the minimum voltage is lower than `-0.5V`?

How can I protect the inputs from negative voltages?

This is a way to protect a MCU pin e.g ADC input from high voltage, but it does not protect if I set GND to `-10 V`. The linear voltage regulator has a diode as protection, but I don't know if that helps.

[image]

**Update:**

Let's say that we have three cases:

Case 1: If `A = Positive`, `B = 0V` and `C = High`, then the zener diode will protect. - OK!

Case 2: If `A = 0V`, `B = Positive` and `C = 0V`, then current is going to flow from `B -> C` and leaving a voltage drop at `A0` depending on how large `R1` is. This can hurt my analog input `A0` - How can I protect it in that case?

Case 3: If `B = Negative` and `A = Positive`, this will hurt my MCU directly. How can I protect it in this case?

[image]

Comment: "How can I protect inputs from negative voltage" -- What are the specifications / range of voltage (min, max) that can possibly appear in that input pin?

Comment: What's the use case here?  Are you afraid of accidental or intentional application of negative voltage?

Comment: In your diagram, what is the source of the "0 V" signal and the "-10 V" signal?

Comment: *"say Vcc = -5V and GND = 0V volt"* [...] *"I set GND = -10V"* It is unclear how the power rails of the uC relate to the other voltages in the circuit.

Comment: @ThePhoton The -10 is the GND and 0V is the input signal. In this case, it's a voltage divider for scale down 0-10V to 0-5V.

Comment: @vir Yes. What if Vcc becomes negative. Will the pin break too if they are attacked with negative voltage?

Comment: If VCC = -5V you don't have to worry about the I/O pin ratings any more.

Comment: @user_1818839 Why not?

Comment: Because you already killed the MCU.

Comment: @user_1818839 Haha. Good one! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How can I protect the inputs from negative voltages?

Using diodes and Zener's is not accurate when protecting inputs for your MCUs.
If you want to protect the input then use a device such as the TLV6001 to buffer the input signals. This is the only way to provide professional protection that is viable for both digital and A/D inputs.

A simple circuit such as this will provide accurate translation of the 0-5v signal for any application.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8RZYH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The TLV6001 (or TLV6004) is rated for rail-rail operation and so allows the full range of MCU range for A/D input ...in addition the device is rated to carry 10mA in the input protection diodes, though you need to provide the series resistor. This allows the configuration shown above to withstand voltages of +/-200 V on the input resistor R2 (providing your resistors are rated for this voltage).
If you only need protection for say 24-58VDC you can reduce the input resistor to suit your need.

Since the TLV600 is powered by the MCU +5 V supply it cannot produce an output voltage above 5 V or below 0 V, so the input is accurately clamped WITHOUT impacting the A/D range at all, and of course this would work for digital inputs just as well. You must make sure that your MCU solution is always drawing a minimum current greater than your expected protection current (this is only an issue if you put things into a sleep state).

You always need to provide a good ground/0V reference on your interface, it is never a good idea to capture signal relative to a power supply rail.

Comment: I like this one!

Answer (score 2):

> But what if I say Vcc = -5V and GND = 0V volt? Then it will break?

Yes, it will break.

You will be forward biasing the ESD protection diodes on every IO pin, and sending uncontrolled current through them. This will almost certainly damage the chip within a fraction of a second.

> How can I protect the inputs from negative voltage?

You can connect a Schottky diode with its cathode connected to the data line and anode connected to ground (the same node as the ground pins of the uC). Use a resistor in series with the signal to limit current through the Schottky diode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fECVib.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes! I have a zener diode. Do you think that's OK?

Comment: But what if the GND has negative voltage?

Comment: Do not use a zener diode on an analog input! The zener diode will begin to conduct before the rated voltage and cause analog errors.

Comment: @MrYui, no you want a Schottky diode, not a Zener. A zener will likely have a high enough forward voltage to provide no protection to the internal ESD protection diodes.

Comment: @MrYui, As long as the anode of this protection diode is connected to the same node as the GND pins of the uC it will protect against the INPUT signal going to an even lower voltage.

Comment: @MrYui - the net we label "GND" is by definition 0V - always - otherwise it wouldn't be GND. GND is the reference for every other voltage measurement you make in your circuit. So your question "But what if the GND has negative voltage?" doesn't really make much sense...

Comment: @Kartman You're wrong. Zener does not create nonlinearity. I have modify a zener today and it becomes very linear.

Comment: @brhans What if some one change it? They set negative voltage on GND by misstake?

Comment: @ThePhoton But I need to use a zener because I want to have a maximum limit for the voltage.

Comment: @MrYui, voltage is a measurement between 2 points. If "They set negative voltage on GND", then where is the 0V you're measuring this negative voltage from?

Comment: @brhans Hmm...if I set GND = negative voltage and then Vcc will have a linear voltage regulator + diode, then Vcc will have negative voltage as well. In this case...will that hurt the MCU because all pins have -0.5V tollerant level?

Comment: @MrYui Please post a **complete** schematic with: the microcontroller, the voltage regulator and the analog input circuit

Comment: @devnull I can't do that in Falstad. I don't have the knowledge how to write that up inside a schematic program.

Comment: @MrYui, the picture you're trying to draw with words just doesn't make sense. You need to actually draw what you're trying to describe before this conversation can go much further. But I strongly suspect that once you draw it you might start to see the contradictions in what you're describing... If Falstad won't cooperate then draw it on paper and take a pic if you must. But this site also has a built-in schematic editor you can use if you edit your question.

Comment: @brhans Ok. give me 5 min

Comment: @brhans Done now.

Comment: @MyYui, if I’m wrong then there is probably something incorrect in your circuit! If you care to search, one of the learned contributors did an excellent explanation of why using a zener is a bad choice recently.

Answer (score 2):

Voltage is relative, you are correct there.  BUT you can't put things in opposite polarity, because in the context of the microcontroller, you're going outside it's operating parameters according to the datasheet.

> But what if I say Vcc = -5V and GND = 0V volt? Then it will break?

Yes, it will break.

Now an interesting thing you can do with this knowledge is to run the microcontroller with `Vcc=0V` and `Gnd=-5V`.  Note, this doesn't violate the datasheet, and note the **polarity**!  `0V` is greater than `-5V`.
Also, if you were to do something like this, you'll need to run your **entire** circuit at these *shifted* voltages, or else make a properly designed voltage translator to interface to something that is running at the more common `Gnd=0V` reference.

EDIT: After seeing more comments on the OP, this answer doesn't really apply to the OP, but leaving it for anyone else who needs to do some non-common circuit design.

Comment: Good post!  FYI, we do this a lot in the GaAs RF world.  These devices like to be powered with 0V and -5V.  In order to control them, the inputs need to stay within that range.  So we power the controlling digital device with Vdd (Vcc) =0V and GND (or Vss) = -5V.  Then we level translate whatever is providing the inputs to the controlling digital device.

Comment: @SteveSh Thanks! On my first job out of college I was tasked with running a 5V chip off a 24V supply by hanging it off the 24V rail and create a 19V rail for ground.  Bent my mind a bit, but opened my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution. I use a PNP transistor.
Now when I apply -10V, then I get very low voltage to the MCU pin.
If I apply +10V, then I get 5 voltage to the MCU pin because the zener diode is at 5V level.

[image]

Or one could use a simple "fools diod" between ground and input. Then all the current will flow from GND to the input.

[image]